# React native app-release build not working for some android devices

Tags: android, react-native

I gave a build for android using gradlew assembleRelease.
but app-release.apk file not working for some devices like honor 9i, Redmi note 5 pro.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your app is compatible with OS of your device. Enable installation from unknown sources. Sign your app before sending .apk. It is important due to security restriction of some devices.
[signing your app](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

Happened to me on some devices as well. Even if you allow installation from unknown sources turned on. Some devices alter the final .apk file (maybe for security reasons). So we used android playstore publish for distributing app as test/beta builds. Pick one appropriate for your pre release distro. It should work fine.

Comment: i followed all the steps but still facing same this issue.

Comment: did you try releasing your testing version from playstore? If that didn't  work as well then it might be react-native bug which requires reporting

Comment: I didn't try with playstore. Actually if i run react-native run-android --variant=release it is working fine in mobile but if i run gradle assembleRelease the apk file not working in my phone. In some phone its working.

Comment: I don't have exact explanation but happened in my case for honor phones. My final solution was to release as beta using playstore (you can release for specific users using other test release if you don't want your app to show to public)